# Provide JSON as data for rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: json, richfaces

I am implementing a full text search in my project and for that the result of search comes from SOLR server as JSON.

Is it possible to provide JSON for `data or value` attribute of the `richfaces` component `extendedDatatTable or simple dataTable`.

Resultant JSON would look something like :

`resultObj = {

```
    "numberOfResults":25,
    "results":[
    {
        "instanceId":100,
        "inj_Name":"Inj4",
        "i_IdentificationNumber":127,
        "noz_Name":"Nozzle4",
        "n_IdentificationNumber":460,
        "thr_Name":"Throttleplate4",
        "t_IdentificationNumber":0,
        "act_Name":"Atuator4",
        "a_IdentificationNumber":781
    },
    {
        "instanceId":100,
        "inj_Name":"Inj4",
        "i_IdentificationNumber":127,
        "noz_Name":"Nozzle4",
        "n_IdentificationNumber":460,
        "thr_Name":"Throttleplate4",
        "t_IdentificationNumber":0,
        "act_Name":"Atuator4",
        "a_IdentificationNumber":781
    } ]
};
```

`

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no you can't. Your best bet would be to reflect this data into a `List` of Java objects using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and then use that list as a data source.

Comment: I tried many ways and it seems to be not possible to provide JSON directly to richfaces tables. GSON is one option, i ll have to try.